The fastest way of applying Entity Framework Core migrations to create a new database
We have ~150 integration tests that run in parallel. To ensure they are isolated, we create a fresh database each time. To create the database we call DatabaseContext.Database.MigrateAsync().
Unfortunately with each additional migration the time to set-up the database increases.
Alternatives I've tried that haven't reduced the total time:

Calling EnsureCreated
Restoring from a .bacpac file
Disabling parallelism in tests and using the Respawn library to reset the shared database

The only success I've had is to delete all the existing migrations and create a single migration in its place. This reduces the total test time significantly - by up to 50%. This feels like a hack though and I don't want to add some additional recurring maintenance step.
What's the fastest way of creating a fresh database for tests?

I have always opted to use backups and restores for integration tests. I have multiple database images with preset data, these are not complete production-like databases, just sample sets with data set up for various scenarios suited to certain areas. Integration test fixtures are configured to use the most relevant image and restore to a uniquely named database. When the test succeeds the database is dropped. If a test fails, it is left for inspection and dropped manually.

Integration tests do take a significant amount of time to run through completely which is why they are only run periodically and prior to a release candidate nomination. I have seen them run as part of a CI/CD setup on each check-in but this really slowed down development. Instead I prefer to gate-keep them to a process with a branch on release nomination where they are run as part of that process and ad-hoc prior to that. Unit tests /w no data dependency are run as part of CI.

I assume that you're creating the backups manually?
I wanted to make the tests as self-contained as possible and have it fit with the normal migration process, so that anyone could run the test in their IDE, or add test data in the test itself programatically.
I know that integration tests can be slow, but I believe they can be improved. Our ~150 tests take 5-7 minutes to run and the majority of the time is creating the database. With a single migration they're much faster, so I know it's EF that's the bottleneck

Yes, I create/adjust the test database images manually. 5-7 minutes for an integration run of 150 isn't terrible. While on larger projects I may have several thousand unit tests, I'd typically have less than 1000 integration tests which would run in around 20 minutes or so. I have worked in environments where they insisted running them as part of the CI pipeline which sucked. Personally when given the option I use release branching so they run only on the release candidate branches, or ad-hoc on Trunk. I'd be surprised if effective integration tests could be set up and run in under 5 min.

I've found a simple way to initialise the database without making a call per migration:
private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;

public async Task InitializeAsync()
{
    await using AsyncServiceScope scope = _factory.Services.CreateAsyncScope();
    SampleDbContext dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SampleDbContext>();
    // this is using types normally hidden to application code
    IRelationalDatabaseCreator databaseCreator = dbContext.Database.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>();
    // needed for idempotency if retrying this method due to transient errors
    await databaseCreator.EnsureDeletedAsync();
    // creates database without schema
    await databaseCreator.CreateAsync();
    // script is not idempotent nor executed in a transaction
    string script = dbContext.Database.GenerateCreateScript().Replace("GO", "");
    await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(script);
}

Things that could be improved:

Using types/methods that are on the public EF API, rather than resolving infrastructure services
Generating an idempotent script so that it can be re-run in case of errors

